# Weird IE8 layout glitch - why does the body background disappear?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

This is one of those "what the bloody hell" problems that I don't even know how to approach.

I have this website: http://www.mojalbum.com and if you open it in IE8 it loads fine, and after half a second the layout gets messed up. If you then resize the window it gets back to normal. Also if you open developer tools and disable and re-enable a CSS property (does not matter which one) the layout gets fixed too.

Unfortunately I can't remember when this started happening so I don't know what I did that caused this. And I really have no idea what to do. I've spent 3 hours searching for a solution on google without any luck (to be honest I'm not really sure what to search for).

Here is the messed-up screenshot:
[image]

And this is how it should look:
[image]

I'm using Internet Explorer 8 (v 8.0.7601.17514) on Windows 7.

Edit: I've now managed to (kinda) isolate the problem. If jQuery (v1.6.1) is included on the page then this thing happens. Including jQuery v1.3.2 does not cause this problem.

Comment: The site does have HTML and CSS validation errors.  Perhaps cleaning those up will result in a fix?  Good luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer below is now mostly obsolete, because the problem has been fixed as of jQuery 1.6.2, which has been out for a while now.

If you're having this problem, just **upgrade jQuery** to the newest available version.

---

Edit:

There's something wrong *with jQuery*!

If I switch to 1.6.1 hosted from Google, it still breaks: http://jsbin.com/epata3/3

If I move the `script` to inside the `head`, **it works**: http://jsbin.com/epata3/4

And you're right, everything works as expected with 1.6.0: http://jsbin.com/epata3/7

***???***

---

<strike>There's something wrong with your jQuery include.</strike>

This simple test case breaks in IE8 in exactly the same way:

**See in IE8:** http://jsbin.com/exomi4

The background flashes red, then turns white.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>

<style>
body {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mojalbum.com/js.php?f=core/jquery_1.6.1.js,&c=v2"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep, very very wired. I'll use your example to fill a bug report if you don't mind.

Comment: Good idea. I'm interested to hear what the cause of this is.

Comment: The bug has been fixed for the next release (1.6.2), you can get the fixed version here: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js

Answer (score 2):

I've reverted the jQuery version back to 1.6 (from 1.6.1). This fixed the issue.