# strange ie8 css behavior - disappearing/re-appearing background color?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have a page that simply has a dark-grey background for the `body` with a `div` in the foreground that has a white background. In every other browser besides IE 8 (even IE 7 seems to work fine!) the page is rendered fine. However, in IE8, I see the background color for a split second before it turns into white. Even more bizarre, when I open up the developer tools on IE8, the dark grey background re-appears!

I've tried this on 3 different computers now each with slightly versions of Windows, with the same results.

My only solution so far is to apply the dark grey background color to the `html` element which seems to work, but I'm fairly sure this is non-standard.

Any suggestions? Is this a known bug?

Comment: Had this happen to me, and could replicate it with IE 9 rendering as IE 8. Marking as favorite and +1. HTML5, by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the version of jQuery you're using (`v1.6.1`).

I came across the same problem in this question, it has all the info you need: [Weird IE8 layout glitch - why does the body background disappear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149820/weird-ie8-layout-glitch)