# Post loading jQuery with Opera

Tags: jquery, html, css, background, opera

I am post loading jQuery and it is causing a CSS error in **Opera** (and Opera alone). I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39DQJ/2/) to demonstrate.

Having some CSS that styles the HTML and BODY tags like:

```
html {
    background: #6B9AB6;
}

body {
    background: white;
    max-width: 10em;
}
```

Then post loading jQuery (using a simple `setTimeout` for demonstration purposes):

```
setTimeout(function(){

    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js';

    var script_sib = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    script_sib.parentNode.insertBefore(script_tag, script_sib);

}, 2000);
```

Causes the correct CSS to display, then flash to an unstyled HTML tag. Using Opera's DragonFly and changing either the `background-attachment` or `background-origin` dynamically fixes this. The same is not true if you do this programmatically.

Is there a way to make Opera behave with postloaded jQuery? Feel free to update the JSFiddle if you have any ideas.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but there was something similar with IE8 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149820/weird-ie8-layout-glitch, but that doesn't seem to be relevant here.

Comment: have you tried `$('<script src="..." />').appendTo('head');` otherwise you should google api to load it when you want to ..

Comment: Have you tried removing the background color from the HTML selector?

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks - need the HTML selector as I am changing the background colo[u]r.

Comment: @Val - it works. http://jsfiddle.net/39DQJ/5/ - because it doesn't load jQuery, $() is only available after you load jQuery. The problem is that when jQuery is loaded, the HTML background-color disappears.

Comment: oh right, well you have html tag have a background, and then you have body have a different background, may I ask why ?

Comment: @Val It means I don't need to make a content container element for proportional CSS designs that use max-width based on ems. The body kinda is that tag when you want to show a background to larger screen extremities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a regression in jQuery version 1.6; [jQuery version 1.5.2 works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/39DQJ/9/).

For now there [is a patch](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9239) by Aderty:

> The bug can be resolved on ligne [line number] 1288 from jquery-1.6.1.js.
>
> Replace :
>
> "documentElement.insertBefore( body, documentElement.firstChild );"
>
> by
>
> "documentElement.appendChild( body );"

which works wonders if you are self-hosting the library.

**EDIT:** Version 1.6.2 has a fix for this issue (currently in [jQuery's GIT](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js) repo).

Comment: Interesting. It was similar to the IE8 thing after all.