# IE8 and lower showing background white

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background

I am having a weird problem with ie8 and lower. I apply a backgound image and color to the body element with CSS. The background is, however, painted white in IE8 and lower when I load the page.

In the moment i resize a little bit the window the background is correctly applied.

```
body {
     background-image: url(../images/main.gif);
     background-repeat: repeat-x;
     background-position: top left;
     background-color: #6e9b68;  
}
```

[A live site suffering this problem](http://artesaniadelrey.com).

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Just visiting that page in IE8 crashes for me -- it redirects to index.html, then tries to "recover" the tab after an error, then redirects to res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm#artesaniadelrey.com,http://artesaniadelrey.com/index.html, then dies. Have you got some crazy Javascript going on? Can you reproduce the problem *just* with HTML and CSS?

Comment: Thirtydot, below, was right. It was a Jquery bug. I moved to 1.5.1 and it works. Thanks for looking into the problem Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the version of jQuery you're using (`v1.6.1`).

I came across the same problem in this question, it has all the info you need: [Weird IE8 layout glitch - why does the body background disappear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149820/weird-ie8-layout-glitch)