# background image is not being displayed in IE 8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

The content div background is not being displayed in IE8.

Here is the css

```
#content{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 950px;
    height: auto;       
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;       
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: url('images/content-bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
}
```

All other browsers show the image.
When testing in IE9's developer mode using browser mode to IE8 and document mode to IE8 the image is visible but not in IE8 itself.

Comment: Are you by any chance using jQuery on this page? If yes, which version?

Comment: OK I see that you are. Try this: use the latest version of jQuery and tell me if the problem persist. You may be suffering from this bug that I had recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149820/weird-ie8-layout-glitch-why-does-the-body-background-disappear

Comment: Is [this](http://webtrial.tk/wordpress/wp-content/themes/allister/images/content-bg.png) the image you want to show? It is `content-bg.png`, not `content-bg.jpg`.

Comment: @SalmanA the images exists as they are visible in all browsers

Comment: Thanks for your collaboration

Comment: I have solved my problem by just converting .jpg to .png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change background-image url. It will work.

```
background-image: url("/wordpress/wp-content/themes/allister/images/content-bg.jpg");
```

Comment: i have solved the problem by changing .jpg to .png thanks for your answer

Comment: what? did you not actually have the .jpg version of the file and were trying to load it? did you have the .png from the very first?

Answer (score 0):

write like

```
background: url('images/content-bg.jpg') no-repeat 0 bottom #FFF;
```

Comment: Typo: It should be #fff and not $fff.

Comment: or may be you were thinking about $$$$$s :)